# What was life like in the 1920s to 1930s in Bruno, Saskatchewan?

Tags: canada, 1920s, 1930s

What was the population, demographics, and types of services that they would have had?

Looking for an overview of that whole area during the 1920s and '30s.

Would most babies been born at a hospital or at home?